# alternative picture source for html webpage

Tags: javascript, html

i have a html webpage with some pics.
The pics are on the local pc.
The problem is there are two possible locations for the pic.
So i wonder if its possible to add an alternative picture path if the first path doesn´t exists.
I know it´s possible with php but it would be nice if there is another solution.
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code

`<img src="first_image_link" onerror="this.src='second_image_link';">`

Answer (score 0):

you could try s.th like that:

```
<img src="foo" altsrc="bar">
```

JS (jQuery):

```
$(function(){
   $('img').on("error",function(){
      $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("altsrc"))
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you could checkout the error event beeing thrown if the src points to 404

sth like :

```
  image.onerror = function () {
    image.src ="newsrc.jpg";
  }
```